# Reject drag/drop based on object data?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, drag-and-drop

I have c# DataGridViews modified so that I can drag and drop rows between them.  I need to figure out how to either disable dragging on certain rows, or reject the drop for these rows.  The criteria I'm using is a value in the datarow.

I'd like to disable the row (gray it out and not allow drag) as my first choice.

What options do I have?  How can I disable or reject drag-drop based on criteria?

Comment: Can you check the index of the row after the dragging occurs? that would be the trick

Comment: @Mr.DDD -Can you elaborate?  What are you suggesting?

Comment: You are dragging rows between the others, aren't you? Well, if you could check the index of the row being dragged on (i.e. the row which the new row will be next to it), you can accept/reject the dragging. That depends on the rows indeces.

Comment: @Mr.DDD -I still don't understand.  The index of the row is not the criteria I'm filtering on.

Comment: You criteria is `a value in the datarow`. Ok, with the row index, you can access your `value on the row` and check it.

Comment: Ok....but when?  Where?  In some event?

Comment: In the DragDrop event, @MAW74656. The DragDrop event args should contain the object being dropped. Cast that to DataGridViewRow, check your value. I have a sample I can get to later this afternoon if someone doesn't give you an answer by then.

Comment: @IAbstract -Yes, I think I will need an example.  How do I cancel the drop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to prevent a row from being dragged at all, use the following method instead:

```
void dataGridView1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)e.Data.GetData(typeof(DataGridViewRow)); // Get the row that is being dragged.
    if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "no_drag") // Check the value of the row.
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None; // Prevent the drag.
    else
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move; // Allow the drag.
}
```

Here, I presume you start the drag operation by doing something like this:

```
DoDragDrop(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0], DragDropEffects.Move);
```

In this case, you don't need to use the method from my previous answer, of course.

Comment: -Where dataGridView1 is the source grid (where the row starts)?  Or is it the destination in your example?

Comment: -I'm still missing something.  The DragEnter event of the source grid is never fired (because I'm never entering that grid).  DragOver and DragLeave don't work either.

Comment: Ups, my mistake. It should be the destination grid. I guess I've done enough coding for today; I'm getting careless :)

Comment: I did not use this answer as shown, but this answer was the most useful, and helped me to find a better way.  This works, but I felt like the user should be stopped sooner from dragging the row.  I set up something in the mouse_down event of the source grid to stop the dragging right away using similiar code.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample method that should get you started:

```
    void dataGridView1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Point cp = PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y)); // Get coordinates of the mouse relative to the datagridview.
        var dropped = dataGridView1.HitTest(cp.X, cp.Y); // Get the item under the mouse pointer.
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[dropped.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "not_allowed") // Check the value.
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None; // Indicates dragging onto this item is not allowed.
        else
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move; // Set the drag effect as required.
    }
```

You should, of course, use it like this:

```
dataGridView1.DragOver += new DragEventHandler(dataGridView1_DragOver);
```

Modify the condition in the if-clause to your needs. Currently, it disables dragging onto a row if the first cell value equals to the "not_allowed".

Comment: -I don't quite understand... I'm not dragging anything onto a row, I'm dragging entire rows between datagridviews.  I'm not sure how this applies?

Comment: @MAW74656 You stated in your question that you want to disable dragging **on** certain rows, and this is what the code do. It prevents row A being dragged onto the row B if B has a special value. Are you instead trying to prevent row A being dragged (onto whatever) at all?

Comment: Correct, I want to prevent a row from being dragged (at all) based on some value in it.

Comment: @MAW74656 See my next answer, then. You might also consider editing your question for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dodragdrop.aspx

You can override DragEnter and DragLeave functions to achieve

In DragLeave - you can query your object based on selection and cancel operation if the object does not have the required value

Cheers

Comment: -How to cancel the dragging operation?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit late but I had the same issue today. I wanted to prevent a drag of a list item in some situation.

I ended up using the _ItemDrag event handler. Inside the handler I checked wether dragging the Item was allowed and if not I used a SendKeys.Send("{ESC}"); command to cancel the drag.

```
//Prevents dragging tree items that have at least one child item 
    private void lvTaxonomyItemLedgerAccounts_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e) 
        { 
           LedgerAccountTaxonomyItem accountTaxonomyItem = ((OLVListItem)e.Item).RowObject as LedgerAccountTaxonomyItem; 
           if (_ledgerAccountTaxonomyItems.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ParentAccountId == accountTaxonomyItem.Id) != null) 
               SendKeys.Send("{ESC}"); 
        }
```